# How to not repeat "example" in this sentence

Tags: repetition

> For example, in the previous example, an HTML element containing ``Search Results" can be used as an anchor.

How to say it so that "example" doesn't repeat?

Comment: Can you add the sentence before this one? With just this one, it is hard to tell which example should go.

Comment: Say "For *instance*, in the previous example..."

Answer (score 2):

You can just omit "for example" altogether. If you start the sentence by referring to the previous example, it's immediately clear that you're talking about an example, not a universal case.

> In the previous example, an HTML element containing ``Search Results" can be used as an anchor.